# How to use Sequelize to update the quantity of my items in my cart DB if it already exist or create it if it don't?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I' am a beginner programmer working on building an e-commerce site, I'm currently stuck at implementing my cart feature. The stack I'm using is the NERP stack (Node, Express, React-Redux, and Postgres). I'm trying to update the quantity of my items in my cart's DB if already exists and if not create it the item in my DB using Sequelize.

```
      //api/cart.js

    const router = require('express').Router()
    const Cart = require('../db/models/cart')
    module.exports = router

    router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      Cart.findAll()
        .then(items => res.send(items))
        .catch(next)
    })

    router.put('/', (req, res, next) => {
       if(req.body){
           Cart.update(req.body, {
               where:{
                   quantity: req.body.quantity++
               }})
           .then(() => res.sendStatus(204))
           .catch(next)
       }
       else{
           Cart.create(req.body)
           .then(item => res.send(item))
           .catch(next)
       }
   })

    router.delete('/:cartId', (req, res, next) => {
        Cart.findOne({
            where: { id: req.params.cartId }
        })
        .then(item => {
            item.destroy()
            res.send(item)
        })
        .catch(next);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `upsert`:

```js
// create a new row object with the updated values you want
const updatedRow = Object.assign({}, req.body, {
  quantity: req.body.quantity++,
});


// "upsert" that new row
Cart.upsert(updatedRow)
.then(() => res.sendStatus(204))
.catch(next)
```

You can find more information in the [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert).

Comment: I'm sorry, but where exactly would I implement this in my code, because I tried replacing the code under my if statement and it don't seem to be working.

Comment: @JoshuaLeMay Please provide more information on what's happening when you try it. Any errors? Maybe we can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I get this error in my nodemon..column "nan" does not exist.And in my console, when i hit my add button on my site I get this error...TypeError: Cannot create property 'quantity' on string ' '.